# Hreflang tags in wordpres

Tags: seo, wordpress, multilingual, hreflang, tags

I am using RankMath plugin and there is no Hreflang tags in this. Is there any way I can add same on all pages using any trick or somthing?

Comment: Before moving forward, do you need hreflang? Is your site built for multiple languages?

Comment: Yes, i am planning to multi lang functionality but not sure to use this hreflang with ranmath. I researched lot of things but no proper solution so far.